# Regex replace but ignore last character

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regex-group

I am trying to replace

```
/ok/how/are
```

with

```
$ok, $how, $are
```

using regex

```
str.replace(/\/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/g, '\$$1,')
```

and result is

```
$ok, $how, $are,
```

I can't use another statement to remove last leading `,` how can I get desire result without last `,`

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex?

Comment: yeah without regex, this is easy string manipulation assuming the input format is always as your example dictates

Comment: You can use your current solution and just slice the last comma, eg: `'/ok/how/are'.replace(/\/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/g, '$$$1,').slice(0, -1)`

Comment: I can't use any function else than .replace

Answer (score 3):

You can use two captured group, one with end of string anchor another without anchor and replace value accordingly

```js
let str = `/ok/how/are`
 
let final = str.replace(/\/([a-zA-Z\d]+)$|\/([a-zA-Z\d]+)/g, (_, g1, g2) => g1 ? `$${g1}` : `$${g2}, `)
   
console.log(final)
```

Comment: could you please explain this? any possiblity using it without condition. I will use it vscode snippet

Comment: @WasimA. here we are having two capture group and based on captured group we pass the replace value. no you either need condition or you need to use two regex

Answer (score 2):

If the only function you can use in [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), you can use your pattern and replace the trailing comma with an empty space.

```js
const regex = /\/([a-z0-9]+)/g;
let str = `/ok/how/are`;
str = str
  .replace(regex, "$$$1, ")
  .replace(/, $/, '');
console.log(str);
```

Another option without a regex could be using a combination of [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a forward slash, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to prepend a dollar sign and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on a comma and space.

To remove the empty entry after split you could use for example `.filter(Boolean)`

```js
let str = "/ok/how/are";

str = str.split("/")
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(x => "$" + x)
  .join(", ");

console.log(str)
```

Comment: I don't have anyother option to use else than regex and replace.

Comment: @WasimA. I have updated my answer using another replace to remove the trailing comma and space.

Comment: that's great but unfortunately in vscode snippet we can't use second replace

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions are possible: if it's about replacing `/` with `$` and separating the resulting terms with a comma this may be viable.

A second solution is using *named capture groups* ([see here](https://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-named-capture-groups.html) and snippet) in your regular expression

```js
console.log( `$${"/ok/how/are"
  .split("\/")
  .filter(v => /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/g.test(v))
  .join(", $")}` );

// use es2018 named capture groups in regex
// -----------------------------------------
console.log( "/ok/how/are".replace(/\/((?<end>\w+$)|(?<within>\w+))/g,
    (...args) => {
      const { within, end } = args[args.length-1];
      return within ? `$${within}, ` :  `$${end}`;
    })
);
```

Comment: I don't have option for jquery or anyother function, only regex and replace.

Comment: @WasimA. this answer doesn't uses `jQuery` at all, it's just pure vanilla JS only

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variant of lambda/anonymous function based approach in `.replace`. This regex uses a capture group inside a lookahead that asserts whether we have `/` ahead of us or it is end of string.

```js
let str = '/ok/how/are';

var repl = str.replace(/\/([a-z\d]+)(?=(\/|$))/ig, 
           ($0, $1, $2) =>  '$' + $1 + ($2 ? ", " : ""));

console.log(repl);

//=> "$ok, $how, $are"
```

**Details:**

- `\/([a-z\d]+)`: Match `/` followed by 1+ letter (ignore case) or digit
- `(?=(\/|$))`: Lookahead that asserts presence of `/` or end of string and captures it in 2nd capture group
- `($0, $1, $2)`: Here `$0` will be full matched string and `$1, $2` are first and second capture group
- `'$' + $1`: Concatenates `$` and 1st capture group
- `($2 ? ", " : "")`: Use ternary operator it makes a decision whether capture group #2 or `$2` is empty or not. If it is not empty then it adds `", "` in final output otherwise an empty string is added.

Comment: could you please explain this part ($0, $1, $2) =>  '$' + $1 + ($2 ? ", " : "")

Comment: Sure will add explanation in answer.

Comment: you guys are awesome, could we do  it without using (_, g1, g2) => g1 ? conditioning. I am actually try to make vscode snippet and it doesn't accept conditions

Comment: Unfortunately it will be either a conditional thing OR 2 calls to `.replace`